# How to reload the custom JavaScript file after Drupal makes ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, drupal

How one can reload the custom JavaScript file after an Ajax call is completed?

In my case I have a custom JavaScript file to manipulate the views data and
filters. It works perfectly the first time a page is loaded.

But once the user sets a filter and hits Apply i.e. after the Ajax call, the JavaScript seems to stop working. It's there but not registering any event.

I read some articles on Drupal.org but that didn't give me a solid solution.

Note - Its not a module .js file but a custom stand alone .js file under the theme folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read up on [JavaScript in Drupal](http://drupal.org/node/121997), especially [any part about `Drupal.bahaviors`](http://drupal.org/node/114774#javascript-behaviors).

The main point is that you need to turn your custom JavaScript file into Drupal.behaviors, because those will get reattached to content loaded dynamically via AJAX like calls.

Answer (score 1):

the question could be - "how can I fire a js function with updated on a dupal call back parameters"

this is what I did:

my form like this:

```
$form['letterdrop_id'] = array(                       
    '#type' => 'select',                              
    '#title' => 'Letterdrops',                        
    '#options' => $letterdrops,                       
    '#prefix' => '<div id="replace_div_ld">',         
    '#suffix' => '</div>',                            
    '#ajax' => array(                                 
      'callback' => 'agc_ems_form_map_change',        
      ),                                              
    );
```

with this call back function:

```
function agc_ems_form_map_change($form, &$fstate) {              
   return array(                                                 
    '#type' => 'ajax',                                           
    '#commands' => array(
      // this command is to reload a form element                                        
      ajax_command_replace("#agc_map", render($form['map'])),    
      // this command does the business and calls my custom function, 
      // with a parameter object supplied
      array('command' => 'afterAjaxCallbackExample',             
          'selectedValue' => 'i am not a fish',                  
    )                                                            
  ));                                                            
}
```

this is my js function

```
(function($, Drupal) {                                                      
  // put function into drupal commands:   
  Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.afterAjaxCallbackExample = 
     function(ajax, response, status) {
    // response object as passed in our Ajax callback          
    // do what you want in here
    alert(response.selectedValue);                                          
  };                                                                        
}(jQuery, Drupal));
```

100% credit to [jaypan](http://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/calling-function-after-ajax-event-drupal-7)

Answer (score -1):

To add a script you need to use document.createElement("script") you can't just set innerHTML. see http://www.phpied.com/javascript-include-ready-onload/ for a good example that deals with seperate browsers.